# How to add Wishlist/Add to Cart in all products shown in front page in drupal 7?

Tags: commerce

I am work on commerce_kickstart site. I was created 3 views in my front-page. In each view 3 products are there. I want to add Wishlist/AddToCart below in the list of every product. How can i do this. Please Help. Thanks

[image]
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and enable the [Commerce Wishlist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_wishlist) module and in views add the **Commerce Product: Add to Cart form** field, then you can see Wishlist/AddToCart button. Also Enable the checkbox "Link products added to the cart from this display to the current path the customer is viewing where the View is rendered".

Don't forget to set permission and configuration.

> Features
>
> - Provides an “Add to Wishlist” button on the display product node;
> - Creates a customizable list with Views to display all products on the Wishlist – both as a page and as a block;
> - Recognizes and stores product variations;
> - Makes it possible for users to easily delete or switch products in their Wishlist to their Shopping Cart with the click of a button;

Comment: I already installed but I have a problem that in my view I am not getting any option "Commerce Product: Add to Cart form"...@Bala

Comment: You have to use relationship under advanced section and then add "Content: Referenced products"

Comment: May u pls first help me to fetch the price. Actually I am unable to fetch the price also... @Bala

Comment: Please check the "Require this relationship" for "Content: Referenced products"

Comment: After doing this... products are going to disable @Bala

Comment: Ok uncheck it, what is the problem your facing actually ? once you added the  "Content: Referenced products" in relationship you can add any product variations fields. and we are going out of topic please try different combinations to achieve your requirement.

Comment: if I check the "Require this relationship" for "Content: Referenced products" then all the products of the view is not visible & if I uncheck the "Require this relationship" & add field i.e "Commerce Product: Price" then nothing show except product image

Comment: Ok uncheck the  "Require this relationship" for "Content: Referenced products"  and then try it

Comment: Plz read my above comment.. @Bala

Comment: I can't understand for what am I add filter criteria for getting Price of every product.

Comment: Its too long unable to comment here. How can i provide you. @Bala

Comment: actually i am working on a development server...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17290/discussion-between-samzha-and-bala).

Comment: sent pls check... http://tempsend.com/6D3CDAA381

Comment: I want to discuss with you @Bala